# How to use 'Update file and folder names' in Banshee

Tags: banshee, files

When using 'update file and folder names' in Banshee it will leave the old folder after creating a new folder.

This clutters up the ~/Music(or wherever) directory.

Can it delete the old folders? Or just update the old folder names rather than creating a new one and then risk deleting any info in the old one?

Answer (score 2):

It removes empty folder but **pay attention**: if the folder contains non-music files (like .m3u, .txt, subfolders with various stuffs, etc...) these file **are not moved** and the folder is not deleted.

So the first time you put a folder in music library you may have some *ghost folders*.

Comment: Exactly the case

Answer (score 0):

I was fairly sure that Banshee attempts to clean up after itself by deleting empty folders when 'update  file and folder names' is set.  If that's not the case for you, you should [open a new bug report.](http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/)

Comment: I guess some folders contained non music files, like album art.